# Storing and querying pricing structures which differ for each row?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, database-schema

I've been struggling to think of a good way to store this data...

Each row is a doctor's practice. Each practice has a price which differs for each age group. For example one practice might have this pricing structure, where the left is the age and the right is the price:

```
0: 0
13: 20
21: 35
35: 35
60: 20
```

However the structure varies from practice to practice. So another practice might have this:

```
0: 5
25: 50
40: 35
60: 20
```

I need to be able to fetch the price for any given age.

Currently I have all the prices stored in a JSONB column on each row. I grab the JSON object in nodeJS and run an algorithm to get the price for an age. Surely this isn't ideal, but I can't think of any way to store and query this in postgres.

So far I've considered having another table for fees and storing each age/price couple like this:

```
name | age | price
```

but that seems kinda clumsy and would create many thousands of rows. The other idea I had was to have columns for the cost at each possible age on the practice row like this:

```
name | 0 | 5 | 6 | 13 | 16 | 18 | 21 | 25 | 40 | 60
```

but that also seems incredibly clumsy and unwieldy.

Any ideas? Or maybe I'm better off just keeping it in JSON?

Comment: Your original format with an id for the practice seems quite reasonable.  I would have a lower and upper age limit for each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would store the prices in a separate table that defines the "interval" in which the price is valid:

```
create table practice
(
  id integer not null primary key,
  name text
);

create table prices
(
  practice_id integer not null references practice,
  from_age integer not null,
  to_age integer,
  price integer not null,
  constraint valid_interval check (from_age < to_age)
);
```

You can also add an exclusion constraint to prevent overlapping intervals:

```
CONSTRAINT no_overlap 
   EXCLUDE USING gist (practice_id WITH =, int4range(from_age, to_age)  WITH &&)
```

Of course instead of using two columns `from_age` and `to_age` you could put that into a single `int4range` column which has the benefit of being indexable. As you typically will query per practice that only leaves a very small number of rows to go through so the index on the range column isn't necessary (or won't help)

To query the price, you just do:

```
select price
from prices
where practice_id = 42
and 25 between from_age and to_age
```

As the condition `practice_id = 42` already narrows this down to just 5 or 6 rows, this is quite fast. Even if you have thousands of practices.

Comment: Edit: Actually I think I misunderstood you... Hold on

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, the price depends on the combination of practice and age. How about make a table with 3 columns:

> Practice_ID | Age | Price

Where the Practice_ID and Age are the primary keys. That way you can query for the price with the practice and age.

Comment: Yeah that was my first idea but it seemed a bit odd to me. I have 1000 practices and if each has 5 price categories that's 5000 extra rows in the pricing table. Also how would I query for an age between the categories?

Comment: Yes, if you have 1000 practice and each has 5 price categories, that makes 5000 possible combination.

Comment: Isn't that quite a lot of rows? I mean if I need age 7 which lies between age 0 and 13.

Comment: It isn't really a lot of rows. Your problem is the range querying (eg. `age = 7` where 7 isn't a value in the database. I'm thinking you could declare the AGE and PRICE columns as parallel arrays, but I haven't come up with a query syntax yet.

Comment: The query for an age between categories (7 in this case), you can do something like this: Select top 1 Price from TableA where Pratice_ID = @PracticeID and Age >= 7  order by Age. This will return the price for age = 13

Comment: @Pancakes: 5000 rows is _nothing_. When I create test data, I usually don't create less than 100.000, most of the time a lot more.